# PowerShell Change Download Folder Pathway in Network Share

Tags: powershell

I have this script that downloads files from a report server and puts those files in a local network share. The script does what it needs to, but the download folder looks like this hitsqlp -> Extracts -> output -> web16p...this is the pathway of where the folder needs to live, but it is replicating that pathway into subfolders so now I have to click on every subfolder to get to the files.
I want the folder 'SSRSFolder' to be a subfolder of \epicsqlt\Extracts\Output\HIT\web16p

Code below, I'm not sure where I went wrong:

```
set-location -path \\epicsqlt\Extracts\Output\HIT\web16p
$downloadFolder = "\\epicsqlt\Extracts\Output\HIT\web16p"
$ssrsServer = "blahblahblah"

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $secpasswd)
$ssrsProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "$($ssrsServer)" -Credential $mycreds
 
$ssrsProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "$($ssrsServer)" -UseDefaultCredential
 
$ssrsItems = $ssrsProxy.ListChildren("/", $true) | Where-Object {$_.TypeName -eq "DataSource" -or $_.TypeName -eq "Report"}
 
Foreach($ssrsItem in $ssrsItems)
{
    # Determine extension for Reports and DataSources
    if ($ssrsItem.TypeName -eq "Report")
    {
        $extension = ".rdl"
    }
    else
    {
        $extension = ".rds"
    }
     
    Write-Host "Downloading $($ssrsItem.Path)$($extension)";
 
    $downloadFolderSub = $downloadFolder.Trim('\') + $ssrsItem.Path.Replace($ssrsItem.Name,"").Replace("/","\").Trim() 
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $downloadFolderSub -Force > $null
 
    $ssrsFile = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
    [byte[]] $ssrsDefinition = $null
    $ssrsDefinition = $ssrsProxy.GetItemDefinition($ssrsItem.Path)
 
    [System.IO.MemoryStream] $memoryStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream(@(,$ssrsDefinition))
    $ssrsFile.Load($memoryStream)
    $fullDataSourceFileName = $downloadFolderSub + "\" + $ssrsItem.Name +  $extension;
    $ssrsFile.Save($fullDataSourceFileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i'm reading this right.

you are starting the script with

set-location -path \epicsqlt\Extracts\Output\HIT\web16p

then you are setting the $downloadfolder variable to that path and including $downloadfolder in your $downloadfoldersub creation.

so the result would be

epicsqlt\Extracts\Output\HIT\web16p\somepath\somefolder\

and then you are creating a new-item with that whole path, when you are already working in the \web16p\ folder.

Comment: Correct. The new item is my download folder -- "/SSRSFolder/" So it sounds like because I have the whole path specified in $download folder, it is creating that pathway of folders, to fix that, should I remove that whole pathway and just put /SSRSFolder/?

Comment: i don't see "ssrsfolder" in your script, so i'm guessing that's part of "$ssrsItem.Path." if you can hard-code ssrsfolder, great. or you can experiment with removing the set-location OR removing the "$downloadFolder.Trim('\') + " from $downloadsub.